# Is it possible to run a local SQL Azure instance?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm developing/testing a .NET application which needs to access a live SQL Azure instance. (Yes, it has to be an *Azure* instance, because it's using code that's specific to Azure, not just SqlClient stuff.)

In order to prevent accidental data changes, I'd prefer to run the application against a local instance rather than the live one.

Copying the schema/data is another issue, but as long as I can execute SQL against the local instance, I can take care of it.

Is it possible to run SQL Azure on my local development machine?

(I'm using Windows 7, but can move to Windows Server if necessary.)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106433/is-there-a-local-emulator-for-sql-azure . What is it about the SQL side of things that is Azure specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do isn't possible at this time.

Microsoft recommends using SQL Server 2008 in place of SQL Azure for development purposes. You can use any version (Enterprise, Standard, Express). The majority of the functionality is the same but there are some key differences you need to know when migrating, which can be found here: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9692818

If you're doing something that REALLY needs SQL Azure, and the other versions of SQL Server just don't cut it, your only other option would be to provision a separate database instance from Azure and create a firewall rule to allow your development environment access to it.